# Redshift, count items in column seperated with comma

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have data that a column saved a group of number

```
|  user   |      col                     |
| ------- |         -------              |
| 1       | 3,7,11,25,44,56,77,32,34,55  |
| 2       | 3,7,25,44,37,89,56,99,103,13 |
| 1       | 3,10,11,25,44,56,33,32,34,55  |
```

I know I can split part the columns and count but do we have any different way to count the numbers?

```
|user| new-col | count|
| -------      | ------- | 
| 1   | 3      | 2 |
| 1   | 7      | 1 |
| 1   | 11     | 2 |
| 1   | 25     | 2 |
| 1   | 44     |2  |
| 1   | 56     |1  |
| 1   | 77     | 1 |
| 1   | 32     | 2 |
```

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: I need to find each counted number of numbers in col per user. I have an idea to have the result of each number

Comment: @Axis Please edit your question to **show us your desired output** for example data you have provided.

Comment: @johb Rotenstein question updated. I am trying to avoid to use the Union table because I have a big table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a union query along with `SPLIT_PART`:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT user, SPLIT_PART(col, ',', 1) AS val FROM yourTable UNION ALL
    SELECT user, SPLIT_PART(col, ',', 2) FROM yourTable UNION ALL
    SELECT user, SPLIT_PART(col, ',', 3) FROM yourTable UNION ALL
    SELECT user, SPLIT_PART(col, ',', 4) FROM yourTable UNION ALL
    SELECT user, SPLIT_PART(col, ',', 5) FROM yourTable UNION ALL
    SELECT user, SPLIT_PART(col, ',', 6) FROM yourTable UNION ALL
    SELECT user, SPLIT_PART(col, ',', 7) FROM yourTable UNION ALL
    SELECT user, SPLIT_PART(col, ',', 8) FROM yourTable UNION ALL
    SELECT user, SPLIT_PART(col, ',', 9) FROM yourTable UNION ALL
    SELECT user, SPLIT_PART(col, ',', 10) FROM yourTable
)

SELECT
    user,
    val,
    COUNT(*) AS cnt
FROM cte
GROUP BY
    user,
    val;
```

But note that all we are doing above in the CTE is really just normalizing your data so that each user-value relationship occupies a separate record.  Ideally you should change your table design and move away from storing CSV.

If you instead want just the count of numbers per user, then use:

```
SELECT
    user,
    COUNT(*) AS cnt
FROM cte
GROUP BY
    user;
```

Comment: Great solution, @Tim. Thanks (Sorry a bit late)

Answer (score 1):

Count the number of commas in the string using `REGEXP_COUNT` and add 1.

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE examples (
      user_id INT
    , value_list VARCHAR 
);
INSERT INTO examples
          SELECT 1 , '3,7,11,25,44,56,77,32,34,55' 
UNION ALL SELECT 2 , '3,7,25,44,37,89,56,99,103,13'
UNION ALL SELECT 1 , '3,10,11,25,44,56,33,32,34,55'
;
SELECT user_id
     , SUM(REGEXP_COUNT(value_list,',')+1) value_count 
FROM examples
GROUP BY 1
;
```

Output

```
 user_id | value_count
---------+-------------
       1 |          20
       2 |          10
```

Answer (score 0):

This answers the original version of the question.

You can count the number of comma-delimited values with:

```
select (case when col = '' then 0
             else length(col) - length(replace(col, ',', '')) + 1
        end) as values_count       
from t;
```

That said, you should fix your data model so you are not storing multiple values in a column.  It is particularly irksome that you are storing numbers as strings, as well.  You want a junction/association table.

Comment: Sorry, @Gordon for confusing, I need to count each separated numbers per user. Like, 3 counted two times for user1

Comment: @Axis . . . Fix your data model!

Answer (score 0):

Query.

```
with t as (
select 1 as user, '3,7,11,25,44,56,77,32,34,55' as col 
union all
select 2 as user, '3,7,25,44,37,89,56,99,103,13' as col
union all
select 1 as user, '3,10,11,25,44,56,33,32,34,55' as col
)
select a.user, a.val, count(*) as cnt
from (
    select a.user
      , SPLIT_PART(a.col, ',', b.no) as val
    from t a
    cross join (
      select * from generate_series(1,10) as no
    ) b
) a
group by a.user, a.val
order by a.user, a.val
```